# Numerical Integration within lsqcurvefit function handle

Tags: matlab, math, optimization, curve-fitting, mathematical-optimization

Need to optimize C parameters in func handle using lsqcurvefit. func handle is also calling multiple handles one of them being L_(@Vf) which contains integral function. The problem is when I want to optimize the C parameters, I need to give an array of Vf values but integral function only takes double or scalar values. How to solve this problem?

```
L_= @(Vf) integral(@(t) sqrt(a_(Vf).^2.*sin(t).^2+c_(Vf).^2.*sin(t).^2),0,theta_(Vf));
func = @(C,Vf) 2.*(L_(Vf)./r_1-(L_(Vf)./r_1).^(-2)).*C(1) + 2.*(L_(Vf)./r_1-(L_(Vf)./r_1).^(-2)).*2.*C(2).*((L_(Vf)./r_1).^2+2./(L_(Vf)./r_1)-3) + 2.*(L_(Vf)./r_1-(L_(Vf)./r_1).^(-2)).*3.*C(3).*((L_(Vf)./r_1).^2+2./(L_(Vf)./r_1)-3).^2+ 2.*(L_(Vf)./r_1-(L_(Vf)./r_1).^(-2)).*4.*C(4).*((L_(Vf)./r_1).^2+2./(L_(Vf)./r_1)-3).^3;

C0 = [1; 1; 1; 1];

C = lsqcurvefit(func,C0,Vf_data,W_data);
```

Is there any way to optimize the C parameters inside a for loop or something which can avoid this situation?

Comment: Try using `func_array = @(C, Vf_array) arrayfun(@(Vf) func(C, Vf), Vf_array);` instead of `func` in `lsqcurvefit`.